# Reading XML File via Grok Exporter

Tags: xml, grok

I am using Grok exporter to find out error lines.
I am able to do that with .log files.
However, whenever, I am trying to use the same with XML files, I am not getting desired result.

**

- For Example:-

Below is my log file:-

```
  2016/07/30 14:37:03 alice 1.5
    30.07.2016 14:37:33 Adam 2.5
    30.07.2016 14:43:02 bob 3.5
    30.07.2016 14:45:59 Bill 4.5
    31.07.2018 14:45:59 Baren 5.5
    30.07.2018 14:45:59 Joe 6.5
    30.07.2018 14:45:59 Right 7.5
    30.07.2018 14:45:59 Jess 8.5
    30-07-2018 14:45:59 Nathan 9.5
    30.07.2018 15:45:59 Suzi 10.5
```

Grok Config File:-

```
    input:
        type: file
        path: ./example/example.log
        readall: true
    grok:
        patterns_dir: ./patterns
    metrics:
        - type: counter
          name: grok_example_lines_total
          help: Example counter metric with labels.
          match: '%{DATE} %{TIME} %{USER} %{NUMBER}'
    server:
        host: localhost
        port: 9144
```

Output:-

```
    # TYPE grok_exporter_lines_total counter
    grok_exporter_lines_total{status="ignored"} 1
    grok_exporter_lines_total{status="matched"} 9
```

Same thing when I am trying to do for xml file, all lines are getting ignored.
XML Code:-

```
   <Cat>Exception</Cat>
          <DateTime>2017-02-17T21:12:44.4677331-02:00</DateTime>
```

Grok Config File:-

```
input:
    type: file
    path: ./example/example.xml
    readall: true
grok:
    patterns_dir: ./patterns
metrics:
    - type: counter
      name: grok_example_lines_total
      help: Example counter metric with labels.
      match: '%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}'
server:
    host: localhost
    port: 9144
```

In Grok debugger, grok expression is matching with 2017-02-17T21:12:44.4677331-02:00, however, in metrics all lines are getting ignored
Output:-

```
# TYPE grok_exporter_lines_total counter
grok_exporter_lines_total{status="ignored"} 5
grok_exporter_lines_total{status="matched"} 0
```

**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, grok_exporter doesn't support multi-line capturing, Says by the creator of grok_exporter on [fstab/grok_exporter#46](https://github.com/fstab/grok_exporter/issues/46#issuecomment-428318550)

> grok_exporter does not support multi-line patterns. The reason is that
>   grok_exporter processes the log file line by line. Whenever a new line
>   is written to a log file, the patterns are applied to the new line
>   only, and the metrics are updated accordingly. I don't think there is
>   a straightforward way to support multi-line patterns, because that
>   would mean that if a new line is written to a log file, the entire
>   file had to be re-processed.

Logstash is an alternative that has multiple codec plugins for your purpose.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html#plugins-codecs-multiline